# MFC how to get CString from another Class to CRegSettings class

Tags: c++, string, class, mfc, registrykey

I have a problem about save Edit text to registy.
I did in main class save to registy text data and i did another registry class that call
CRegSettings  so this class doing enum each time when i clicked button like 
MyItem\0, MyItem\1.

my problem is i cant get that CString text into this CRegSettings  class, this class doesnt have DoDataExchange so when i did it somehow its turn to error "CMySettingsItem::DoDataExchange' : recursive on all control paths" so it's doesnt work and i cant get CString from main class to this class, does anyone know how to do it ? Thanks.

Here is my codes.

Main.cpp

```
// CNewConnectionDlg dialog

IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(CNewConnectionDlg, CDialog)



CNewConnectionDlg::CNewConnectionDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
: CDialog(CNewConnectionDlg::IDD, pParent)
    , m_csIp(_T("localhost"))
    , m_csPort(_T("22"))
    , m_csUsername(_T("Username"))
    , m_csPassword(_T("Password"))

{

}

class CMySettingsItem : public CRegSettings
{
public:
    DWORD Id;

    CString m_Password;
    CString Password;


    BEGIN_REG_MAP(CMySettingsItem)
        REG_ITEM(Id, 1)
        REG_ITEM(Password, m_Password)
    END_REG_MAP()
protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);

};

// Sample application configuration
class CMySettings : public CRegSettings
{
public:

    DWORD RootId; // DWORD option
    CString RootName; // String option
    std::string FullName;

    // list of options (CMySettingsItem)
    CSimpleArray<CMySettingsItem> Profile;  // ATL CSimpleArray
    //std::list<CMySettingsItem> ProfileList;   // STL list

    CMySettingsItem SubItem; // Subitem test

    BEGIN_REG_MAP(CMySettings)
        REG_ITEM(RootId, 1)
        REG_ITEM(RootName, "Profile")
        REG_ITEM_STL(FullName, "Profile")
        REG_ITEM_SIMPLE_ARRAY(Profile)
        //REG_ITEM_LIST(ProfileList)
    END_REG_MAP()
};

void CMySettingsItem::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CMySettingsItem::DoDataExchange(pDX);

    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_PASSWORD, m_Password);


}

CNewConnectionDlg::~CNewConnectionDlg()
{   
    AfxGetApp()->WriteProfileString("Settings", "UserName", m_csUsername);
    AfxGetApp()->WriteProfileString("Settings", "IP",       m_csIp);
    AfxGetApp()->WriteProfileString("Settings", "Port",     m_csPort);
    AfxGetApp()->WriteProfileString("Settings", "Password", m_csPassword);




    CMySettings configuration(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software\\MyItem\\Item");

    // Load configuration
    if(configuration.Load() != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        printf("failed to load\n");

    // Use loaded configuration
    configuration.RootId++;

    CMySettingsItem item;
    item.Id = configuration.RootId;

    configuration.Profile.Add(item); // CSimpleArray
    //configuration.ProfileList.push_back(item); // list

    // Save new configuration
    if(configuration.Save() != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        printf("failed to save\n");



}


void CNewConnectionDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);

    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_IP, m_csIp);
    DDV_MaxChars(pDX, m_csIp, 255);

    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_PORT, m_csPort);
    DDV_MaxChars(pDX, m_csPort, 6);

    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_USERNAME, m_csUsername);
    DDV_MaxChars(pDX, m_csUsername, 20);

    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_PASSWORD, m_csPassword);
    DDV_MaxChars(pDX, m_csPassword, 255);

}


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CNewConnectionDlg, CDialog)
    ON_EN_CHANGE(IDC_PASSWORD, &CNewConnectionDlg::OnEnChangePassword)
    ON_EN_CHANGE(IDC_USERNAME, &CNewConnectionDlg::OnEnChangeUsername)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void CNewConnectionDlg::OnEnChangePassword()
{

}


void CNewConnectionDlg::OnEnChangeUsername()
{

}
```

And Header

Main.h

```
#pragma once
#include "InnerDlg.h"
#include <afxtempl.h>

class CNewConnectionDlg : public CDialog
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CNewConnectionDlg)

public:
    CNewConnectionDlg(CWnd* pParent = NULL);   // standard constructor
    virtual ~CNewConnectionDlg();

     CNewConnectionDlg(const CString sSection, const CString sArrayName);

    // Dialog Data
    enum { IDD = IDD_NEWCONNECTION };


public:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support

protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
public:

    // The server ip or name
    CString m_csIp;

    // The negotiating port on the server
    CString m_csPort;

    // Username for the server
    CString m_csUsername;

    // Password for the server
    CString m_csPassword;


    afx_msg void OnEnChangePassword();
    afx_msg void OnEnChangeUsername();

};
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answer.

Yep my app is Dialog based, so how can i declare item ?
i mean can you please show me item.m_Password = m_csPassword;  with more detail
because says for item , this declaration has no storage class or type specifier.

Thanks again.

Comment: Like these ?  CMySettingsItem item;
item.Id = configuration.RootId; item.m_Password = m_csPassword;  configuration.Profile.Add(item);                                   But this is didn't worked still i get empty Registry Key.

Comment: Alright i figured it out it's worked it's item.Password = m_csPassword;  and worked. Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DoDataExchange` is only intended for user interface classes, such as your CDialog-based class. It is used to connect the user interface elements on screen with the member variables of that object. So your data is sitting in the m_csIp, m_csPort, m_csUsername, and m_csPassword members. You just need to assign it to the relevant member of your `CMySettingsItem` instance.

For example:

```
item.m_Password = m_csPassword;
```